# What is the Fast Way on remembering the Japanese adj/verb pronouciations and its related meanings?

Tags: words

By far, I found the most difficult and important parts of learning Japanese words is to memorize its pronounciations.

eg.
あつい　. It means Hot, an adjective. But how can I relate the two - pronouciation and meaning - together, except repeatedly memorizing ?

From the English learning experience, we can start learning words by the roots and suffix, and then expand the vocabulary, which could save a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: This question falls under "asking for advice", and is not on topic

Comment: What root or suffix did you rely on to first learn that the English word “hot” means what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Besides brute force memorizing (you will have to do this anyway), you should learn kanji early. For instance, consider:

> 悲しむ
>
> "to be sad"

> 悲しい
>
> "sad"

And other compounds will have this too:

> 妥協
>
> kanji for "gentle" + kanji for "cooperate", the word means "compromise"

Note that pronunciations won't always work. Kanji characters can be read a few different ways usually. For more on the topic, search something like "on'yomi vs kun'yomi"

Comment: Thanks.  For Chinese speakers, some of the Kanjis are not a big problem.  For example, for あたたかい, if I miss one, it will not have the meaning -warm-  which is really troubling. Any ideas ?